# How can I perform sum on calculated column in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
select top 20 percent 
    orders.OrderID, od.unitprice * quantity as total_sales, 
    c.CustomerID,ContactName, phone
from   
    Orders
inner join 
    [dbo].[Order Details] as od on Orders.orderID = od.OrderID
inner join 
    customers as c on c.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
order by 
    total_sales desc
```

[image]

Comment: With GROUP BY and SUM()? So, what level do you want to group to? One record per customer? Per order? Also, what table does `quantity` come from?  Better still, give some example data, and the results you want for that data.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: give some sample examples on exactly what you want to achieve .

Answer (score 0):

you can just add function sum like this :

```
select top 20 percent 
    sum(od.unitprice * quantity) as total_sales
from   
    Orders
inner join 
    [dbo].[Order Details] as od on Orders.orderID = od.OrderID
inner join 
    customers as c on c.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
order by 
    total_sales desc
```

Comment: You're missing a `GROUP BY`, so you'll only get one row, and makes a mockery of `TOP 20 percent` and `ORDER BY total_sales DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

Since orderID column seems unique, I guess you want to have customer wise cum():
So I have grouped the result by c.CustomerID, ContactName and phone to get the sum.

```
select top 20 percent 
        c.CustomerID,ContactName, phone, sum(od.unitprice * quantity) as total_sales

from   
    Orders
inner join 
    [dbo].[Order Details] as od on Orders.orderID = od.OrderID
inner join 
    customers as c on c.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
group by         c.CustomerID,ContactName, phone
order by 
    total_sales desc
```